# wordwrap css property for rich text fields?

Tags: css

I have a description field of RTA and the text in the field is as below:

```
<p style="word-wrap:break-word;">aLongAnnoyingContinuousWordWithNoSpacesInBetweenThemIReallyWantToWrapThisUsingCSSWordWrapStylePropertyButItDoesnotWorkAndSimplyDisplaysAsOneContinuousLine</p>
```

On the UI, It just simply displays as a continuous text and user has to scroll to the right to see the complete text.

When I inspect this text using chrome developer tools, I don't see word-wrap style being applied

How do I get it to work?

Comment: See if the unaccepted answer to this works http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140478/word-break-lightning

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    .wordwrap
    {
    /* wrap long text and urls */
    white-space: pre; /* CSS 2.0 */
    white-space: pre-wrap; /* CSS 2.1 */
    white-space: pre-line; /* CSS 3.0 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla */
    word-wrap: break-word; /* IE 5+ */
    }

<p class="wordwrap">aLongAnnoyingContinuousWordWithNoSpacesInBetweenThemIReallyWantToWrapThisUsingCSSWordWrapStylePropertyButItDoesnotWorkAndSimplyDisplaysAsOneContinuousLine</p>
```

Comment: no, it is not working.. When I see on the UI, it is removing the word-wrap style element.. Does salesforce does support wordwrap style for rich text fields?

Comment: Could you try it on another browser? Salesforce should not be removing it, but I've seen stranger things.

Comment: Looks like Salesforce does not support word wrapping for Rich Text fields, because of that it is stripping off my word-wrap style property..Here is the Link https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrrfAAC

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce does NOT support this issue, it has been 5 years and haven't resolved it yet. [Long strings of adjoining characters do not word wrap in Text Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000187551&language=en_US)