# Word Break - Lightning

Tags: visualforce, lightning, css, slds

I want the string to be transfered to the next line in lightning.
In salesforce classic I would just apply to the element style="word-break: break-all". In lightning there's a [special tag](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/utilities/hyphenation/) for that. But for me it doesn't work.
The image below shows the difference in lightning and classic behavior. 
[image: Classic and lightning compare]

Code:

```
<apex:page controller="testController">
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDSXXX, 'assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.css')}" />
    <apex:pageBlock id="block">
        <div style="word-break: break-all; width: 100px;">
            Classic
            <p >loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong.</p>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div class="slds" style="width: 100px;">
        Lightning
           <p class="slds-text-heading--small slds-hyphenate">loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong.</p>
        </div>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

slds-hyphenate is a newer tag and was added in version 2.1.2.

> Hyphenation utility for non-truncated headings in narrow containers -
>   Utilities › Hyphenation

Update to the latest SLDS css and it will work for you. I just tested it out using 2.1.2 with the following page and it work. Previous SLDS version I had did not work

```
<apex:page id="slds_long_text_example" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" applyHtmlTag="false" showHeader="false" docType="html-5.0">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS212, 'assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css')}" />


    <div class="slds">
        <div style="width: 100px">
            <p class="slds-text-heading--small slds-hyphenate">loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    </html>


</apex:page>
```

Comment: It worked. Strange, because before posting the question I've tried this, but nothing's changed. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar requirement and this worked for me:

**Visualforce/Lightning:**

```
<div class="no-text-overflow">
     loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.THIS .no-text-overflow {
    white-space: normal;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

The looong text should adjust to `<div>` size. Tip: it's a best practice use CSS styles defined with classes, so you avoid long in-line styles.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Why the down vote? is something wrong with my answer?

Comment: I would summarize that the reason you received a down vote is that the OP is specifically asking about using SLDS and while this answer is correct for HTML (OP already said they know how to do it in classic) it does not answer the OP's question.

Comment: Well, this solution actually works for both (lightning and classic). I have my doubts if this question was specifically pointed to work with SLDS since I understand that OP used that as an option, hence my answer was an alternative.

Comment: Title "Lightning" and "In lightning there's a special tag for that" seems pretty clear OP is looking for answer on why SLDS tag did not work. And OP states "In salesforce classic I would just apply to the element style="word-break: break-all". which means they do not need a HTML solution.

Comment: In such case I'd suggest `Word break in Lightning with SLDS` for question title since, IMHO, just ' word-break' makes the assumption (mistakenly maybe) that the question had a broader scope than just SLDS.

Comment: I mean, the original title was `string transfer lightning`, which was even more vague. I feel like paying close attention to tags can be helpful, but I'm surprised this instance was down-vote worthy. And `slds` was never tagged. Or really mentioned except in the markup. I don't understand why the question itself would be any more exempt from that voting pattern. (I don't think down-vote was fitting in either case, as the question showed research and the answer was useful). Also note the OP tried `word-break: break-all`, which is not what's recommended here.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Sorry for the wrong topic name - I must've set it clearer that I'm talking about **slds**, not lightning itself. Will try to write it clearer and more certain next time. I've tried your code and it doesn't work for me :( But, Eric gave me the needed tip (to use newest  slds library).

Comment: I was wrong - your solution also works. And especially, it works properly in styled with slds <table> and <apex:pageBlockTable>. *slds-hyphenate* doesn't work as expected - the string represented as one, without transfer.

Comment: Nice!, I forgot to mention that in a way, I'd rather use standard html/css/javascript solutions in lightning sometimes because some components provided by lightning frameworks have some limitations for now. I hope this will change with future releases.

Comment: +1 Joca's solution - slds-hyphenate didn't work for me either. Plus I've used `word-break: break-all;` instead